# Datatables data priority / column priority

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net) for my web apps and using responsive extension that will auto collapse my table column when the screen get smaller and there is also a feature called column priority that will make some column will not collapsed/will be the last one that will collapse if the screen to small.

I can make it work from javascript side with using

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
        { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 }
    ]
} );
```

But there is a little drawback in this method since I have different kind of datatables in each page that have different column that I want it to stay and not collapsed, so I can't really use that code, thankfully there is a better way by adding

```
data-priority="value"
```

Into `<th>` tags, but after I tried it not working it still collapse the column that I already given data-priority, anyone know why?

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-priority="1">First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Extn.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this trick with Jquery

```
var columnDefs = [];
$datatable.find('th').each(function (i, el) {
            var $el = $(el);
            if ($el.is('[data-priority]')) {
                var defs = { responsivePriority: $el.data('priority'), targets: i};
                columnDefs.push(defs);
            }
        })
```

and then use columnDefs in Datatable initialisation